# How to get CartDiscounts for particular cart?

Tags: commercetools

I recently work with Commercetools platform and I have such a question.

How can I get a CartDiscounts for some particular cart? Now I have method for get Cart by Id and I wanna get all CartDiscount from Cart. How I can do that? Or CartDiscount applies to all Cart and I can do something like CartDiscountsQuery.of()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discounts are stored on the line items, custom line items and the shipping method of a cart.

For the shipping method you can get the discounts like so:

```
final Cart fetchedCart = client.executeBlocking(CartByIdGet.of(id));
final List<DiscountedLineItemPortion> includedDiscounts = fetchedCart.getShippingInfo().getDiscountedPrice().getIncludedDiscounts();
```

Please consult the API reference docs for further information.
https://docs.commercetools.com/http-api-projects-carts.html#shippinginfo

Comment: Yes, that great, but how it can be done for LineItems? I found out the hardest way with four loops)

Comment: `Reference<CartDiscount> ff = cart1.getLineItems().get(0).getDiscountedPricePerQuantity().get(0).getDiscountedPrice().getIncludedDiscounts().get(0).getDiscount();`

`CartDiscount discount = executeRequestBlocking(CartDiscountByIdGet.of(ff.getId()));`

Comment: Or maybe I can get List<CartDiscounts> by list of CartDiscounts id?